# Clojure: What is the easiest way to remove all the nil items in a nested data structure?

Tags: clojure, null

Say we have this nested vector:

```
(def coll [nil [["this" nil "this"] nil] nil "this"])
```

How would you design a `remove-nil` function so that all nil disappear?

```
(remove-nil coll)
;> [[["this" "this"]] "this"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (coll? %) (into (empty %) (remove nil? %)) %) coll)
;=> [[["this" "this"]] "this"]
```

Comment: Or, `(filterv (complement nil?) %)`, etc.